# Does `std::sort()` use threading to increase its performance?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sorting, stl

Does `std::sort()` typically use threading to increase its performance? I realize that this could vary from implementation to implementation. If not, why not?

Comment: Most likely not because you can sort on all the threads available to you.

Comment: Note that libstdc++ and libc++, two of the most prevalent implementations, are open source.

Comment: Since C++17 you can call `std::sort(std::execution::par,  ...)` to have it run in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **[res.on.data.races]/8** Unless otherwise specified, C++ standard library functions shall perform all operations solely within the current thread if those operations have effects that are visible (4.7) to users.
>
> **/9** [ *Note:* This allows implementations to parallelize operations if there are no visible side effects. *—end note* ]

`std::sort` could, in principle, use parallel execution when sorting elements of fundamental type (it wouldn't be observable whether it does), but not user-defined type (unless explicitly given permission via execution policy parameter, of course). The type's `operator<` may not be thread-safe.

Comment: And where could I find more details on the "execution policy parameters"?

Comment: *Where is that quote from?* [The C++ standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/res.on.data.races#8). *Where could I find more details on the "execution policy parameters"?* In your favorite C++ reference, e.g. [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm)